# What is the Fourier Transform of the spatial portion of $Ψ(x,t)=A\exp(-b|x-2|)\exp(-iwt)$?

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-mechanics, wave-equation

What is the Fourier Transform of the spatial portion of $Ψ(x,t)=A\exp(-b|x-2|)\exp(-iwt)$?

I tried applying the regular exponential Fourier transform, but not getting it.

Do you just bring out the $exp(iwt)$? If so, then how do you integrate the $exp(-b|x-2|)exp(-ikx)$ left inside from negative to positive infinity?

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Going straight to the definition of the Fourier transform, we have
\begin{multline}
\mathcal{F}[\Psi](k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{-b|x-2|}e^{iwt}e^{-ikx}dx = Ae^{iwt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-b|x-2|}e^{-ikx}dx \\= Ae^{iwt}e^{-2ik}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-b|u|}e^{-iku}du = 2Ae^{i(wt-2k)}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-bu}\cos(ku)du = \frac{2Abe^{i(wt-2k)}}{b^2+k^2}
\end{multline}
where the substitution $u = x-2$ was used and the [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Basic_calculus_properties) of the integrand was used to simplify the last integral.

Also, this wave function is normalizable. The normalization integral is
\begin{multline}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi^*\Psi dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[A^*e^{-b|x-2|}e^{-iwt}\right]\left[Ae^{-b|x-2|}e^{iwt}\right] dx \\= |A|^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2b|x-2|}dx = |A|^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2b|u|}du=\frac{|A|^2}{b}= 1,
\end{multline}
with the same substitution and parity considerations were used here. So $A = \sqrt{b}$.

Comment: Where is the $1/sqrt(2pi)$? And thank you very much, I'm going over it.

Comment: How did you compute the integral to get $1/b$? for the normalization?

Comment: And how did you compute the integral exp(-bu)cos(ku) from 0 to infinity?

Comment: And how does exp(-iku)=cos(ku)?

Comment: @ArthurKarapetov Note the symmetry of the integral. $e^{-b|u|}\cos(ku)$ is an even function, so its integral over the whole real line is equal to twice the integral over the positive reals. $e^{-b|u|}\sin(ku)$ is an odd function, so its integral over the whole real line is zero. Similarly for the normalization integral, though I skipped over the same $u =x-2$ substitution. I'll make these more explicit in the answer.

Comment: @ArthurKarapetov As for the $\sqrt{2\pi}$, I'm used to using a nonunitary normalization for the Fourier transform. If your problem calls for a unitary one, I can change the answer to reflect that. It just requires dividing everything by $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's linear, so the time portion just comes along for the ride. We can use the [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) to note that
$$\mathcal{F}\left\{e^{-a|x|}\right\}=\frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi^2\xi^2}. $$
This is assuming the unitary, ordinary frequency type of FT. You can use a different column if you're using a different convention.
Together with the shifting theorems, that should get you all the way there. Can you continue?

Comment: I have not a clue what that... squiggly E^2 is. Sorry, could you clarify? Thank you!

Comment: The $\xi$ is the transformed variable of the Fourier Transform. It's the equivalent of $s$ for a Laplace Transform.

Comment: Oh, thank you, good to know.

Comment: @ArthurKarapetov it's the greek letter "xi"